# Error 0x0C80 occurs when reading a disk to load the operating system kernel

Tags: assembly, kernel, nasm, qemu, osdev

When I try to read from a disk using BIOS I get error 0x0C80, here is my code:

```
disk_load:
    push dx
    mov ah, 0x42 ; BIOS extended read routine
    mov dl, 0x80 ; Drive number (0x80 for the first HDD)
    mov si, DAP  ; DS:SI -> Disk Address Packet
    int 0x13     ; BIOS Disk interrupt
    jc disk_error
    pop dx
    cmp dh, al
    jne disk_sectors_error
    jmp disk_success
    jmp disk_exit

DAP:
    db 0x10      ; Size of DAP
    db 0x00      ; Reserved
    dw 16         ; Number of sectors to read, equal to value in dh
    dw 0x1000    ; Offset to buffer
    dw 0x0000    ; Segment of buffer
    dq 1         ; Starting absolute block number (LBA)

disk_success:
    mov bx, SUCCESS_MSG
    jmp disk_exit

disk_error:
    mov bx, DISK_ERR_MSG
    call print_string
    mov dh, ah   ; AH contains the error code
    call print_hex
    jmp disk_loop

disk_sectors_error:
    mov bx, SECTORS_ERR_MSG
    call print_string

SUCCESS_MSG:
    db "Disk was successfully read ", 0

DISK_ERR_MSG:
    db "Disk read error! Error code: ", 0

SECTORS_ERR_MSG:
    db "Incorrect number of sectors read ", 0

disk_loop:
    jmp $

disk_exit:
    ret
```

```
[org 0x7c00]

KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000   ; Смещение в памяти, из которого мы загрузим ядро

mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl       ; BIOS stores our boot drive in DL, so it ’s
                           ; best to remember this for later. (Remember that
                           ; the BIOS sets us the boot drive in 'dl' on boot)
mov bp, 0x9000             ; Устанавливаем стек
mov sp, bp

call load_kernel          ; Загружаем ядро
call switch_to_pm         ; Переключаемся в Защищенный Режим
jmp $

%include "OS/boot/print_string.asm"         ; ф. печати строки
%include "OS/boot/print_hex.asm"            ; ф. печати 16-ричного числа
%include "OS/boot/disk_load.asm"            ; ф. чтения диска
%include "OS/boot/print_string_pm.asm"     ; ф. печати строки (32PM)
%include "OS/boot/switch.asm"              ; ф. переключения в 32PM
%include "OS/boot/gdt.asm"                 ; таблица GDT

[bits 16]

load_kernel:
    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
    mov dh, 16
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    call disk_load
    ret

[bits 32]                   ; Сюда мы попадем после переключения в 32PM

BEGIN_PM:
    mov esp, 0x90000
    call KERNEL_OFFSET      ; Переходим в адрес, по которому загрузился код ядра
    jmp $

BOOT_DRIVE:      db 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I need to read the first 16 sectors and load the kernel, and then go into 32-bit protected mode and execute it

I took the very basis of the code from [Github](https://github.com/thedenisnikulin/os-project)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeQJF.png)

I tried to search on the Internet, but I couldn’t find anything that could help me :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, Return Code `ah = 0ch, Media type not found` could occur when program try to read sectors that not exists. For example, Your image file is made of bootloader (1 sector) and kernel (1 sector), rest 14 sectors are not available. So `int 13h` generates error `0ch`. I don't know, to properly read all sectors create image with size 16 x 512 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### About `disk_load`

> ```
> call print_string
> mov dh, ah   ; AH contains the error code
> call print_hex
> ```

You didn't show us the contents of 'print_string.asm' or 'print_hex.asm' so we can't check whether AH survives the *print_string* call or whether *print_hex* expects DH for an input!

Errorcode 0Ch from the IBM/MS INT 13 Extensions reads "unsupported track or invalid media".
It could stem from your using of an hard-coded drivenumber as in `mov dl, 0x80 ; Drive number (0x80 for the first HDD)`. You *did* pass to your *disk_load* routine, the *BOOT_DRIVE* code that BIOS gave you, then why do you overwrite it?
Also, what's the point of passing a sector count in DH if you're not going to use it and just trust the hard-coded value already in the Disk Address Packet? The same is true for the *KERNEL_OFFSET* parameter. And as [@Nassau wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77705254/error-0x0c80-occurs-when-reading-a-disk-to-load-the-operating-system-kernel#comment136995678_77705254), make sure that the disk image that you create with qemu at least contains those 16 sectors.

> ```
>   cmp dh, al
>   jne disk_sectors_error
>   ...
> disk_sectors_error:
>   mov bx, SECTORS_ERR_MSG
>   call print_string
> SUCCESS_MSG:
>   db "Disk was successfully read ", 0
> ```

The 'ExtendedRead' function does not report about the number of blocks successfully transferred via the AL register! Look for this information in the DAP.
And upon the likely fail, you print a suitable message but allow the CPU to start executing what is a text message! These messages belong to below that final `disk_exit:` `ret`. That way, the *disk_sectors_error* code can correctly fall through into the `disk_loop:` `jmp $` code.

### About the IBM/MS INT 13 Extensions

Never just assume these extensions are available! They come with an 'Installation Check' function that will inform you about their capabilities. Use it:

```
mov  dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
test dl, dl
jns  UseCHS     ; Not meant for drives [00h,7Fh]
mov  bx, 55AAh
mov  ah, 41h
int  13h        ; -> AX BX CX DH CF
jc   UseCHS     ; Extensions not supported
cmp  bx, 0AA55h
jne  UseCHS     ; Not installed
shr  cx, 1
jnc  UseCHS     ; Functions 42h, 43h, 44h, 47h, 48h not supported
```

If the extensions are not available, then either abort with a suitable message or fall-back on the normal CHS (CylinderHeadSector) functions.

### The bootloader

> BIOS stores our boot drive in DL, so it ’s best to remember this for later. (Remember that the BIOS sets us the boot drive in 'dl' on boot)

Your comment has it right, but it goes deeper than this. DL is the **only** register that is guaranteed to hold a meaningful value when your bootloader program begins. You must setup the segment registers and stackpointer yourself and not trust BIOS to have done that for you.

> %include "OS/boot/print_string_pm.asm"
> %include "OS/boot/switch.asm"
> %include "OS/boot/gdt.asm"

Switching to protected mode is not among the things that a bootloader should do! It belongs to the setup code of your kernel.

> %include "OS/boot/print_string.asm"
> %include "OS/boot/print_hex.asm"
> %include "OS/boot/disk_load.asm"

Why do you have so many include files? The little work they do does not justify a separate file, and more importantly they lure you into making these errors. I'm referring to the parameter mismatches between the bootloader and *disk_load*, and between *disk_load* and *print_hex*.
Just insert their actual source texts in the bootloader source.

```
[org 0x7c00]

KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

  cld
  xor  ax, ax
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  es, ax
  mov  ss, ax
  mov  sp, 0x9000
  mov  [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

  mov  bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
  mov  cx, 16
  call disk_load

  jmp  0:KERNEL_OFFSET
; ---------------------------------
; IN (ax:bx,cx,dl)
disk_load:
    mov  si, DAP    ; DS:SI -> Disk Address Packet
    mov  [si+2], cx ; Count
    mov  [si+4], bx ; Offset
    mov  [si+6], ax ; Segment

    test dl, dl
    jns  UseCHS     ; Not meant for drives [00h,7Fh]
    mov  bx, 55AAh
    mov  ah, 41h    ; BIOS.InstallationCheck
    int  13h        ; -> AX BX CX DH CF
    jc   UseCHS     ; Extensions not supported
    cmp  bx, 0AA55h
    jne  UseCHS     ; Not installed
    shr  cx, 1
    jnc  UseCHS     ; Functions 42h, 43h, 44h, 47h, 48h not supported

    mov  ah, 0x42   ; BIOS.ExtendedRead
    int  0x13       ; -> AH CF
    jc   disk_error
    cmp  [si+2], cx
    je   disk_success
disk_sectors_error:
    mov  si, SECTORS_ERR_MSG
    call print_string
    jmp  $
disk_error:
    push ax         ; AH contains the error code
    mov  si, DISK_ERR_MSG
    call print_string
    pop  ax
    call print_hex
    jmp  $

UseCHS:

    ...

disk_success:
    mov  si, SUCCESS_MSG
; ----------------------------
; IN (si) OUT (si) MOD (ax)
print_string:
    lodsb
    mov   ah, 0Eh
.next:
    int   10h
    lodsb
    cmp   al, 0
    jne   .next 
    ret
; ----------------------------
; IN (ax)
print_hex:

    ...

    ret
; ----------------------------
DAP:
    db 16       ; Size of DAP
    db 0        ; Reserved
    dw 0        ; Number of sectors to read
    dw 0        ; Offset to buffer
    dw 0        ; Segment of buffer
    dq 1        ; Starting absolute block number (LBA)
SUCCESS_MSG:
    db "Disk was successfully read ", 0
DISK_ERR_MSG:
    db "Disk read error! Error code: ", 0
SECTORS_ERR_MSG:
    db "Incorrect number of sectors read ", 0
BOOT_DRIVE:
    db 0
; ----------------------------
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```